# Get last X items in vue prop array

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I really did struggle with how to write this and what code to show if any. At the end of the day I am going to use this as a concept and see if someone can just explain how you would do this to help more people globally.

So, on a parent vue file I have `messages: []` This stores an array of items from the database. I am pulling this using a Laravel controller. However, that being said I feel like I need to tackle this via Vue.

Now, inside that array could be 100+ items. I only want to pull the last 10 for example and display them to the user. Here is where things get tricky based on what I have tried so far. I can display 10 - but then when the user adds another message, or a notification shows up, it removes the oldest displayed one and still only shows 10 - I dont want this - I want when it is loaded to show the latest 10 - then as new items show up, it keeps showing them

This is a chat room and I only want to show a bit of history when someone joins the room then allow it to build off of that initial list.

Thoughts on how best to go about this?

EDIT: Here is the code in question

```
        getMessages() {
            axios.get('/chat/room/' + this.currentRoom.id + '/messages')
                .then(response => {
                    this.messages = response.data;
                })
                .catch(error => {
                    console.log(error);
                })
        },
```

Comment: Please provide some code, so we can help better. There are many ways to do it, but without code we can't really pin down your approach. Good to see would be things like where and when do you fetch the messages, how do you build the history array and the implementation of the history elements rendered from the history array.

Comment: It sounds like you want a [computed property](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/computed.html#computed-properties) with a portion of the array returned? How about [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)? Also, as mentioned please post some code. Thanks.

Comment: I have gone and added the code in question. That is under a method. What I want to do is limit what it shows on load but not on future messages.